# Declaring Operator Function

Tags: c++

I need help in operator declarations. In the function to obtain the output, do I need to define "operator+=" function for "test_a" as the argument or even "operator*" function that includes both classes as the arguments. Or it is not needed in this situation? I'm trying to design this for robustness of the program.

```
class test_a
{
    public:
        //including definition of constructor/destructor/etc.
        friend class test_b;
    private:
        float *a_value;
};
class test_b
{
    public:
        //including definition of constructor/destructor/etc.
        test_a output(test_a&);
    private:
        float *b_value;
};
test_a test_b::output(test_a& x)
{
    test_a final_output;
    final_output.a_value[0]+=(b_value[0])*(x.a_value[0]);
}
```

Comment: no, because you're using the += operator on float and that's already a defined operator

Comment: owh...so this means that for '(b_value[0])*(x.a_value[0])', i don't need an 'operator*' function since their on float as well...?

Comment: exactly. The only time you need to overload a operator is when you're using the operator on a object that it's not defined for. if you did test_a += test_b then you'd overload it (of course generally you also overload when it makes natural sense to use the plus operator on an object)

Comment: also if a_value and b_value are not arrays, i suggest using the -> operator for dereferencing. 

final_output->a_value += (*b_value)*(x->a_value);